# CASE WHEN Condition on WHERE CLAUSE (All of them OR Not Equal)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have some status', don't know how many. I must put a condition to only one. For example

@isIncludeClose is parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE
status =
CASE WHEN @isIncludeClose = 1
THEN <all_status>
ELSE <status != 'CL'>
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the parameter is available (contains value). If not (IS NULL), then return all, otherwise return the selected records.

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  (@myParameter IS NULL OR myField = @myParameter)
  AND (@otherParameter IS NULL OR otherField = @otherParameter)
```

If the `@myParameter IS NULL`, then the condition will evaulate to true for each record, if it has a value, it will only evaulate to true, where the target field contains the specified value (`myField = @myParameter`).

With your example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  (@isIncludeClose != 1 OR status != 'CL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use T-SQL like:

```
IF @isIncludeClose = 1
BEGIN
    --select all
END
ELSE
   --specific !=
END
```

OR A dirty hack(assuming you don't have empty value)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE status !=
      CASE WHEN @isIncludeClose != 1 THEN 'CL'
           ELSE ''
      END
```